# Rendering issue with listview entries

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

A screen capture best describes the issue:

[image]

As you scroll through the list there are previous entries in a frozen state (they dont scroll) which overlaps the entries being scrolled through.

Some details:

- The listview is inside of a Fragment
- The location data is in a contentprovider.
- the listview is synced to the contentprovider through a cursorloader.
- The locations are being added to the contentprovider in a service. A broadcast is sent from the service to the listview notifying it to reload the cursorloader.

I have a feeling there might already be a solution on S.O. but I searched and couldnt find it. Maybe someone can provide a link.

Comment: We need to see some code here...

Comment: How often is your content provider being updated?